# Changing CardIOActivity header and button background colors

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, card.io

I am integrating Card.IO library in my android project and I wanted to know a way to change CardIOActivity header and button background colors.

I have tried following

```
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(CardIOActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

I wanted to inflate a view from this inflator and change the color then.
However, I don't know the name of header xmls and button xmls.

How do I change these respective background colors?

Comment: what are the information you have? do you have layout or view id or anything else.

Comment: nothing. Else I would just inflated it in a view and then set layout parameters.

Comment: My question is how you will recognize which view you want to inflate.

Comment: That's what I said. I don't have that info.

Comment: So suppose 10 buttons are there then which button background you want to change. One more thing is you are in same activity or in different.

Comment: Ok, I will try this. I am on a different activity.

Comment: Atleast you should have Activity object for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are actually looking for but if you are in same activity then you can try this.

```
View root_view = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
```

above statement will give you root view. Now you need to search all children in this view.

```
for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);

    try {
        // IF TYPECAST SUCCESS THEN YOU CAN USE BUTTON FOR YOUR PURPOSE. YOU CAN USE RECURSION FOR YOU PURPOSE.

        Button button = (Button)nextChild;
        // HERE YOU CAN APPLY BACKGROUND FOR YOU BUTTON.
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

The above code is just an idea how you can try to access the button. You actually need to write recursive function to get child views for all childs till child count is 0.